# Calcular años bisiestos entre dos años ingresados

Tags: c

Tengo que elaborar un programa en C que lea dos años, y que encuentre y escriba todos los años bisiestos entre esos dos años.
El programa deberá usar sentencia repetitiva while.

```
int main()
{
    float anio1;
    float anio2;


    printf("Programa que encuentra los años bisiestos");
    printf("que existen entre dos años ingresados");

    printf("Primer año:");
    scanf("%f", &anio1);

    printf("Segundo año:");
    scanf("%f", % anio2);

    while (anio1 || anio2)
    {
 
    } 
}
```

Solo llevo eso; no sé cómo continuar para que el programa reconozca los años bisiestos, ni cómo integrar while.

Comment: POn lo que has intentado y especifica el lenguaje de programacion

Comment: En C y ya agregue lo que he hecho, aunque no es mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para estructurar mejor el código y hacerlo más legible y fácil de mantener creamos una función que se encargue de determinar si un año es bisiesto o no lo es. **Un año es bisiesto si cumple la condición de que es divisible entre **4**, y (no es divisible entre **100** o es divisible entre **400**)**. Esta función recibe como parámetro el año, y retorna **1** (**verdadero**) si es bisiesto, caso contrario retorna **0** (**falso**).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int esBisiesto(int anno)
{
    return anno % 4 == 0 && (anno % 100 != 0 || anno % 400 == 0);
}

int main()
{
   int annoInicial;
   int annoFinal;

   //Aquí vendría la entrada de datos tal como haces en tu código, eso te lo dejo a ti.

   while (annoInicial <= annoFinal)
   {
      if (esBisiesto(annoInicial))
      {
         //Imprimir que annoInicial es bisiesto.
      }

      annoInicial++;
   }
}
```

Dentro del **método main** haríamos el algoritmo que dará solución a tu problema, entramos los dos años a través de las **variables annoInicial** y **annoFinal** las cuales serán de tipo **int**. Posteriormente ejecutaríamos un **ciclo while** que se ejecutará mientras **annoInicial <= annoFinal**, dentro del **ciclo while** preguntamos si el año es bisiesto llamando a la función previamente creada, de ser bisiesto imprimimos que ese año es bisiesto. Posteriormente incrementamos la **variable annoInicial**, y volvería a ejecutarse el ciclo tantas veces hasta que se cumpla la condición de parada.

Comment: De verdad muchas gracias. Disculpa que vuelva a preguntar pero el la parte de Imprimir que annoInicial es bisiesto, como seria? es algo que yo tengo que hacer o es algo que el programa deberia de hacer? (Disculpa si es algo obvio, soy estudiante y no entiendo muy bien)

Comment: @Dhani, lo haces tú con un printf

Comment: printf("Los años bisiestos son:"); quedaria algo asi entonces?

Comment: Así mismo, busca en internet como se imprimen números en C, te dejo esa tarea, es fácil.

Comment: muy bien, muchas gracias de verdad